# Cocos2d .isTouchEnabled doesn't call single-touch methods

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d, when enabling touches by using `self.isTouchEnabled`, I can use a method like this:

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But, for some reason, this one doesn't work:

```
-(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen your code so I can't tell but have you registered

```
      CCTouchDispatcher
```

How to register :

```
       [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

How to unregister/remove to save memory:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
```

Comment: 'sharedDispatcher' is deprecated. Is there another way?

Comment: You should use '[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher]' now, rest is good :)

Comment: Thanks! Havent used cocos2d in a long time so havent realized this

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the documentation for touch events. All is explained there,
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:touchdelegates